# DOM loadhtml extract nodes and child nodes

Tags: php, dom, xpath, foreach, nodes

I have a list of items where I would need to get the list title attribute, the link URL and displayed link text, as well as the span value of each list tag.

```
<ul>
<li class="testclass" title="Title 1 goes here">
<a href="http://examplelink1.com">List Text 1</a>
<span>Second List Text 1</span>
</li>
<li class="testclass" title="Title 2 goes here">
<a href="http://examplelink2.com">List Text 2</a>
<span>Second List Text 2</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

How can I extract each individual list tag and its values with a foreach (since I need to insert the values into a MySQL db afterwards (each value in a different db field).

So far, I can only get them separately:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($list);
$imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a'); 
foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
$link = $tag->getAttribute('href');
echo $link.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

And

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($list);
$imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li'); 
foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
$link = $tag->getAttribute('title');
echo $link.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

I found a script with xpath, but I do not know how to apply it properly to get the specific values I need and use them in a MySQL statement:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMdocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($list);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("//*");
foreach ($elements as $element) {
echo "<p>". $element->nodeName. "</p>";
$nodes = $element->childNodes;
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
echo $node->nodeValue. "<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DOMXPath::evaluate()`. It is part of `ext/dom` and allows you to use XPath expressions to fetch nodes and values from a DOM.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// use an xpath expression to fetch the li nodes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//ul/li[@class="testclass"]') as $li) {
  var_dump(
    [
      // this is a direct attribute of the li node, use dom method
      'title' => $li->getAttribute('title'),
      // more complex, use an xpath expression
      'href' => $xpath->evaluate('string(a/@href)', $li),
      // Cast the node to a string to return the text content
      'link-text' => $xpath->evaluate('string(a)', $li),
      // works for the span, too
      'description' => $xpath->evaluate('string(span)', $li)
    ]
  );
}
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(17) "Title 1 goes here"
  ["href"]=>
  string(23) "http://examplelink1.com"
  ["link-text"]=>
  string(11) "List Text 1"
  ["description"]=>
  string(18) "Second List Text 1"
}
array(4) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(17) "Title 2 goes here"
  ["href"]=>
  string(23) "http://examplelink2.com"
  ["link-text"]=>
  string(11) "List Text 2"
  ["description"]=>
  string(18) "Second List Text 2"
}
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome! Thank you! Is there a way to echo out only the values in a clean format without an array? I tried foreach($xpath as $key => $val){echo $val;} but it does not seem to work ...

Comment: ok I found a way, just had to echo the value attributes straight without vardump! lol! thank you for your help! much appreciated!